# tengo una referencia sin resolver mContext

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-context

Tengo este codigo para android kotlin pero me da un error de
referencia sin resolver en mContext alguien que sepa cual es el problema

Codigo:

Declaracion de variables y un constuctor

```
class ChatAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter <ChatAdapter.MessageViewHolder?> {

    private var mMessages: List<Message>? = null
    private var mContext: Context? = null
    private var mUserId: String? = null

    constructor(mContext: Context? , mUserId: String?, mMessages: List<Message>?) : super() {
        this.mMessages = mMessages
        this.mContext = mContext
        this.mUserId = mUserId
    }
```

una nueva clase para el uso de las variables anteriores

```
    class IncomingMessageViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        MessageViewHolder(itemView) {
        var imageOther: ImageView
        var body: TextView
        var name: TextView

        override fun bindMessage(message: Message? ) {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(getProfileUrl(message?.getUserId()!!))
                .circleCrop() // create an effect of a round profile picture
                .into(imageOther);
            body.setText(message?.getBody());
            name.setText(message?.getUserId());
        }

        init {
            imageOther = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.ivProfileOther) as ImageView
            body = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvBody) as TextView
            name = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvName) as TextView
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como contexto puedes utilizar el de la propia imagen, es decir:

```
imageOther.context
```

De esta forma, tu código quedaría:

```
    class IncomingMessageViewHolder(itemView: View) :
    MessageViewHolder(itemView) {
    var imageOther: ImageView
    var body: TextView
    var name: TextView

    override fun bindMessage(message: Message? ) {
        Glide.with(imageOther.context)
            .load(getProfileUrl(message?.getUserId()!!))
            .circleCrop() // create an effect of a round profile picture
            .into(imageOther);
        body.setText(message?.getBody());
        name.setText(message?.getUserId());
    }

    init {
        imageOther = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.ivProfileOther) as ImageView
        body = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvBody) as TextView
        name = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvName) as TextView
    }
}
```